# Awk variables concatenated with symbols

Tags: variables, awk, symbols

I am writing a simple bash loop where I use awk to grab lines from a file. The pattern is iterated over in the loop. I can get the program to work fine until I try to add symbols to the variable used in awk for the search pattern

## WORKING PROGRAM (first search term is "cat")

```
list="cat dog"

for k in $list
do
vark="$k" 
awk '/'$vark'/{print RS $0}' RS=\> FILE1 > FILE2
done
```

But when I try to add the symbols "|" ,"<", and "_" to the variable the loop breaks.  I have tried with multiple seperators for the symbols but can not seem to get it to correctly integrate the symbols into the variable.

## BROKEN PROGRAM (first search term is "|cat>_")

```
list="cat dog"

for k in $list
do
vark="$k"
varkk="|$k>_"
awk '/'$varkk'/{print RS $0}' RS=\> FILE1 > FILE2
done
```

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Note that `|` is a special character in awk regular expressions, so you need to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to pass shell/bash variable to `awk` is using `-v` option, like `-v varname="$shell_var"`

**From**

```
awk '/'$varkk'/{print RS $0}' RS=\> FILE1 > FILE2
```

**To**

```
awk -v regexp="$vark" -v RS='\>' '$0 ~ regexp{print RS $0}'  FILE1 > FILE2
```

**You can also do this, using `awk` itself**

```
awk  '
      FNR==NR{ arr[$0]; next }
      { for(i in arr)if($0 ~ i){ print RS $0; next} }
     ' pattern_file RS='\>'  FILE1 >file2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Just to make sure I understand correctly, for the example using regexp where are the "|" and "_" specified? Do I do that directly for "vark" so that vark="|$k>_"    Sorry if this is obvious, still new to awk. Thanks! :)

Comment: @pallascat1492: `-v regexp` is just variable name, that how you should pass shell/bash variable to awk